# Type special characters as Celsius degree symbol directly in SSMS editor

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, char, ssms

I am looking for a way to input special characters directly in SSMS editor. For example I would like to type:

```
select N'37°'
```

How to insert degree symbol directly in SSMS editor while typing? What I have to do now is:

```
select char(176)
```

and copy the symbol to editor window.

Comment: If you are looking for the alt-code. It is alt+248 or alt+0176

Comment: @Peter put it please as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: `select U&'37\00B0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the alt-code. It is alt+248 or alt+0176.